# Getting external (as in not on my Flask app server) json through AngularJS from $http

Tags: angularjs, json, http, flask

I need to get a json file located on a server that has nothing to do with my local server. I thought reading the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) that this would work the following way:

```
app.controller('ctrler_name', [ '$scope', '$http', 'somepageelement', function( $scope, $http, somepageelement ){
      $http.get('/link/to/a/really/external/json')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.backend = data;
           console.log("Got the JSON")
      })
      .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
           console.log(status);
           console.log("Error occured");
      });
} ]);
```

Instead my simple Flask app tried to serve me from:

http://localhost:5000/link/to/a/really/external/json

Maybe I am missing something, everything? How do I access really really remote http resources with Angular?

The error returned by Flask was:

> "GET /link/to/a/really/external/json HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: first of all you must pass an absolute address to `http.get` method. and also consider CORS

Comment: thanks, I think that solved it, will get back if it did not. I just added an 'http:/'. what is CORS anyway?

Comment: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Check out [Flask Cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  You should be able to fix in a few min.